# External DNS Server

Tags: windows, dns, windows-server-2019

I have a network and I want to setup an external DNS server. Here is my idea:

The workstations on LAN make DNS queries to the Domain Controller which is my internal DNS server and the Domain Controller forwards the requests that it gets and doesn´t know how to answer to an external DNS server on my DMZ.

The question here is: my domain queries are internal but other domain queries are external should I make a conditional forwarder to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 through the external DNS Server?

I am a bit confused on how to do this.

Best Regards

Comment: I believe you just want a forwarder, not a conditional forwarder. conditional forwarders only forward traffic upstream for a specific known and predefined name (so for instance you could forward requests for google.com to 8.8.8.8), but they will not forward requests for unspecified domains. an (unconditional) forwarder will forward ALL queries upstream if they are for a zone that isn't hosted on the server. See here for a decent article on it.
https://medium.com/tech-jobs-academy/dns-forwarding-and-conditional-forwarding-f3118bc93984

Comment: and instructions here for configuring (non-conditional) forwarders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/quickstart-install-configure-dns-server?tabs=gui#configure-forwarders

Also why do you want your own DNS server in your DMZ? unless you are hosting public domains, that really isn't necessary.

Comment: The one that contacts with domain outside the organisation will be hosted in my DMZ. I want to keep the services that contact with the internet in the DMZ and the rest in my LAN.

Comment: sure you can do that if you like. completely unnecessary unless you are hosting public domains, but no reason not to do it I suppose. have your domain controllers forward to the dns server in your DMZ, and have it forward to 8.8.8.8 or whatever.